# Why Session_End event not raised when StateProvider is not InProc?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm asking this question out of curiosity.

I noticed this in my global.asax

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
}
```

I want to understand why Session_End event is not captured/raised when the session mode is StateServer or SQLServer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because the [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) it's not in memory anymore...

when using a different process to store the Session State, the **IIS does not know** (because it is not coupled, the session state is not held by the IIS anymore) when the session ends...

this is specially because the timeouts, I never tried, but does that event fires when you programaticaly call Session.Abandon() ??

Comment: I have found on the page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 that "If your data source can be configured to delete expired session data according to the session Timeout property, you can use the SetItemExpireCallback method to reference the delegate for the Session_OnEnd event and raise it when deleting expired session data." So in that case I expect, that overridden RemoveItem method will be called and you can initiate delegate set previously in SetItemExpireCallback method.

Answer (score 2):

The `Session_End` event is only suported by the `InProc` session manager:

> [ASP.NET Session-State Events (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx)
>
> "The Session_OnEnd event is supported
>   only when the session state Mode
>   property is set to InProc, which is
>   the default. If the session state Mode
>   is StateServer or SQLServer, then the
>   Session_OnEnd event in the Global.asax
>   file is ignored. If the session state
>   Mode is set to Custom, then support
>   for the Session_OnEnd event is
>   determined by the custom session-state
>   store provider."

This article explains how to use an `HttpModule` to emulate this functionality:

> [ASP.NET HttpModule for handling session end with StateServer (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SessionEndStatePersister.aspx)

Comment: what about when session state Mode is set to Custom?

Comment: @Sana.91 - probably not, unless you write your customer handler to raise that event.

Comment: @Anti-Santa How can i do that? ... i have been searching for it and there seems no solution..

Comment: @Sana.91 this should get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have found on the page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 that "If your data source can be configured to delete expired session data according to the session Timeout property, you can use the SetItemExpireCallback method to reference the delegate for the Session_OnEnd event and raise it when deleting expired session data." So in that case I expect, that overridden RemoveItem method will be called and you can initiate delegate set previously in SetItemExpireCallback method.