# How to create a limitation for get visit details of page in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function.I get visit details of page like this :

http://www.picpaste.com/pics/IP-jEM861Zb.1391521727.jpg

But I want to get second record after 5 minutes if it is same ip address.How can I do this ?

Global.asax.cs

```
          void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

          {

          Application["hit"] = 1;

          }
```

My function :

```
    public void Hit()

     {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            Application["hit"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["hit"].ToString());


        }
        string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;


        string sayfa = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);

        string browser = Request.Browser.Browser;

        string pcname = Convert.ToString(ipEntry.HostName);

        String IP = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            IP = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        int first = IP.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = IP.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        IP = IP.Substring(first, last - first);
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Hit (Url,Time,Count,Browser,PcName,IpAddress)

       values (@Url,@Time,@Count,@Browser,@PcName,@IpAddress)";

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Url", sayfa.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Count", Convert.ToInt32(Application["hit"].ToString()));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Browser", browser.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PcName", pcname.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IpAddress", IP.Trim());


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




    }
```

And call function in page load :

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Hit();

    }
```

Comment: But I want to get second record after 5 minutes if it is same ip address when page load.How can I do this ?

Comment: You can store data in DB when Session_End is executed - this way you will save single record per client visit.

Comment: How can I store in Session_End ? Can you give some tips ?

Comment: session_end is too limited, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042881/why-session-end-event-not-raised-when-stateprovider-is-not-inproc

Comment: @mikey Thank you mikey but it is not clear for me.I dont know how can I store in session_end.

Comment: session_end is an event in global.asax.  In that event you could execute your database nonquery and write that the session has ended once, when it really ends (rather than write every time a postback occurs from the same user outside 5 minutes).  The problem, however, is that session_end does not always fire (or at all if you're not using inProc, which you shouldn't be using anyway for Session state).  That is why I say it is limited.  Also it fires when the session times out, not when the user actually leaves the site...  Maybe you simply want to check out Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why anyone would want to do that, you have web server logs for this? But you can for example to store the datetime in session and then see if 5 minutes has passed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsNothing(Session("Time")) 
    {
        Session("Time") = DateTime.Now();
        Hit();
    }
    else 
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Session("Time")).Minutes > 4) 
        {
            Hit();
            // Then what do you want? Store information that the 5 minutehit has been made so it does not happen again?
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me if my c# syntax is a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your method.

```
public void Hit()
{
        if (this.Session["FirstHit"] != null)
        {
            var lastHit = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(this.Session["LastHit"]));
            if (lastHit.Minutes > 5)
            {
                this.Session["FirstHit"] = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Session.Add("FirstHit", DateTime.Now);
        }
Rest of your method ...
```