# Cannot get ASP.Net Web Forms application to timeout

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, webforms

I am working on an ASP.Net web forms application.

I want the site to timeout after a certain period, which should be simple, however, I cannot seem to get this to happen as expected.

I have tried changing the timeout settings in web.config, as well as in IIS. I am in SQLServer Session Mode.

Code written in the `Session_End` function of the Global.asax file never executes, regardless of what settings I use for timeout.

Examining the session cookie and ASPStateTempSessions table in SQL Server indicate that the settings that I am changing in web.config are indeed changing the timeout values of the session, however, there is never anything to suggest that the site is ACTUALLY timing out.

I do not know where else to look for timeout settings, or what may be preventing me from generating a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of process session state does not cause Session_End to fire, only in-process as explained in the answer to this question - [Why Session_End event not raised when StateProvider is not InProc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042881/why-session-end-event-not-raised-when-stateprovider-is-not-inproc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If you need to do something after 20 minutes of inactivity (for example) when using the SQL or State Server session provider, you will need to create your own mechanism. There's a link in the question above that explains how to do this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SessionEndStatePersister.aspx